# Typedef redefinition with different types ('struct TGAME' vs 'struct TGAME')

Tags: c

I am having the compiling error of the title.

I have heard it could be because of the name I am giving to the struct, but I change it too many times to random names and that didn't fixed it.

My IDE (CLion), shows that error in PLBR.c

Here are my files:

PLBR.h

```
#ifndef UNTITLED2_PLBR_H
#define UNTITLED2_PLBR_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    int players;
    char diff[5];
    int numpal;
    char *palabras;
}TGAME;
```

PLBR.c

```
#include "PLBR.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct{
    int players;
    char diff[5];
    int numpal;
    char *palabras;
}TGAME;
```

In main.c I just have the #include "PLBR.h" and some code but nothing with relation.

Answer (score 6):

### The Easy Part

This is an interesting question because answering it fully is complicated. Let’s start with the simple answer: To avoid problems, do not redefine a type in a source file. Defining it in the header file and including the header file in the source file is sufficient.

### The Complicated Parts

Now for the complicated parts. You are allowed to repeat a `typedef` definition if it redefines a name to be the same type. C 2018 6.7 3 says:

> … there shall be no more than one declaration of the identifier… except that:
>
> — a typedef name may be redefined to denote the same type as it currently does, provided that type is not a variably modified type;…

So, if you have `typedef int foo;` twice or `typedef char bar[3];` twice, that is fine. You can also have `typedef struct MyStruct foo;` twice.

However, you cannot have `typedef struct { int i; } foo;` twice. Even though the two declarations have identical text, they declare different types. This is because of a rule in C 2018 6.7.2.3 5:

> … Each declaration of a structure, union, or enumerated type which does not include a tag declares a distinct type.

A reason for this is sometimes we use structures that have identical contents for different purposes. For example, we might have a structure with two `double` values that we use for complex numbers (real and imaginary parts) and a structure with two `double` values that we use for points in a plane (*x* and *y* coordinates):

```
typedef struct { double d[2]; } ComplexNumber;
typedef struct { double d[2]; } Point;
```

Having the compiler treat these as different types means it can give us warnings about mistakes like passing a `Point` as an argument where a `Complex` is expected.

So your structure is a different type each time its definition is repeated.

There is a way to refer to the same structure type more than once, and that is to give it a tag:

```
typedef struct MyTag {
    int players;
    char diff[5];
    int numpal;
    char *palabras;
} TGAME;
```

Then we can redefine `TGAME` without error; `typedef struct MyTag TGAME;` may appear, even multiple times, and it redefines `TGAME` to be the same type, `struct MyTag`, which is allowed.

However, although you can repeat the `typedef`, you cannot repeat the structure definition. If you have this twice:

```
typedef struct MyTag {
    int players;
    char diff[5];
    int numpal;
    char *palabras;
} TGAME;
```

the compiler will complain. This is because C 2018 6.7.2.3 says:

> A specific type shall have its content defined at most once.

So, although you can repeat a `typedef` with the same type as many times as you like, you cannot repeat a full structure definition. To use a structure type again, you can only repeat it with the tag alone, not with the full definition of its contents.

### More Complications

After all of the above, the rules about structure tags and types are still incomplete. There are still issues of scope to consider. Using `struct MyTag` inside a new scope can either refer to a previous type or create a new type, depending on how it is used!

Here is an example. The following gets an error because `typedef TypeA TypeB;` does not redefine `TypeB` as the same type it was first defined as:

```
typedef struct Tag { int x; } MyType;   // Create a new type.

void foo(void)  //  Start a new scope.
{
    typedef struct Tag TypeA;               // Define TypeA as previous type.
    typedef struct Tag { int x; } TypeB;    // Make a new type.
    typedef TypeA TypeB;                    // Error, TypeA is not same as TypeB.
}
```

but inserting `struct Tag;` changes the meaning:

```
typedef struct Tag { int x; } MyType;   // Create a new type.

void foo(void)  //  Start a new scope.
{
    struct Tag;                             // Declare struct Tag to be some new type.
    typedef struct Tag TypeA;               // Define TypeA as new type.
    typedef struct Tag { int x; } TypeB;    // Define new type and define TypeB to be that type.
    typedef TypeA TypeB;                    // Works, TypeA is same as TypeB.

    (void) (TypeB *) 0; // (Avoid compiler warning about unused name.)
}
```

The reason for this is there is a special rule for `struct identifier;` appearing just that way, without `{ … }` defining members or as part of a larger declaration like a `typedef`. That rule is C 2018 6.7.2.3 7, which says:

> A declaration of the form
>
> `struct-or-union identifier ;`
>
> specifies a structure or union type and declares the identifier as a tag of that type.

So `struct Tag;` says “We are declaring a new `struct Tag` type in this scope.” In contrast, when we have `typedef struct Tag TypeA;` without `struct Tag;`, then C 2018 6.7.2.3 9 applies. It says that if `struct identifier` “occurs other than as part of one of the above forms, and a declaration of the identifier as a tag is visible, then it specifies the same type as that other declaration, and does not redeclare the tag.” The “above forms” it refers to are the `struct identifier;` I have above and `struct identifieropt { struct-declaration-list }`, which defines a new type by defining its members. So `struct Tag` appears in `typedef struct Tag TypeA;` other than as one of those forms, and a prior `struct Tag` is visible, so this use of `struct Tag` specifies the same type as the previous one, not a new type.

Answer (score 2):

You've already defined `TGAME` in `PLBR.h`. There's no need to redefine it in `PLBR.c`; doing so is not actually allowed.

One of the first stages of the C compiler is to interpret `#include ...` statements by substituting the contents of the referenced files. So by the time `TGAME` is used, the compiler sees this:

```
// Contents of stdio.h
// Contents of stdlib.h
// Contents of string.h

typedef struct {
    int players;
    char diff[5];
    int numpal;
    char *palabras;
}TGAME;

typedef struct{
    int players;
    char diff[5];
    int numpal;
    char *palabras;
}TGAME;
```

Comment: Redefining a typedef name is allowed, as long as the type is the same. The actual problem here is that each structure definition creates a new type, even if the structure contents are identical.

Comment: Now it works. Thank you, I was really stucked with that.